# Mobile Button Menu (Drop Down Menu) goes on to of content

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

the button when clicked makes the menu appear although it does not push the content down, it just goes on top of it and you can't see it. I've tried changing the position of the .navbar but nothing works, I removed the background colour of the navbar to see whether the sidebar and main have disappeared or whether they were behind it (it was behind). Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img class="logo" src="arm.png">
    </header>
    <nav>
        <img class="menuicon" src="menu.png">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="prices.html">Prices</a></li>
            <li><a href="ourwork.html">Our Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

/* CSS */

nav {
background-color: ;
width: 100%;
height: 35px;
}

.menuicon {
width: 35px;
float: right;
}

.hidden {
display: none;
}

.navbar {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 3px;
width: 100%;
background-color: ;
position: relative;
top: 35px;
}

nav li {
width: 100%;
border-left: 0;
text-align: center;
background-color: ;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
}

nav li:nth-of-type(1) {
border-top: 1px solid black;
}

nav li a {
font-size: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar {
width: 100%;
background-color: blue;
}

.main {
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
}

JQUERY
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navbar").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".menuicon").click(function() {
        $(".navbar").toggleClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

Comment: can you add the css and script.js files. Or alternatively create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: the css is there just need to scroll

Comment: heres the query                                                       $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navbar").toggleClass("hidden");
     $(".menuicon").click(function() {
         $(".navbar").toggleClass("hidden");
        });
});

Comment: Try adding display:inline; on the nav. https://jsfiddle.net/2pt7sa71/2/ <- this needs refactoring ;)

Comment: thanks! your a life saver :D